# Elegant way to pass only non-null parameters in rails redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do we pass only non-null parameters in rails redirect_to method ?

I know that we can pass parameters to redirect_to in the following way:

```
redirect_to :action => "action1", :foo => bar
```

Is there any elegant/better way to pass variable 'bar' when it might be nil or empty ?

Right now, I am checking if bar is blank before doing redirect_to. But I feel that this could be done in a more elegant way.

```
if bar.blank?
    redirect_to :action => "action1"
else
    redirect_to :action => "action1", :foo => bar
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a route with optional parameters

```
get '/action1/(:foo)' => 'controller#action1'
```

and then use it like

```
redirect_to :action => "action1"
```

or

```
redirect_to :action => "action1", :foo => bar
```

for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters

Comment: how is this more elegent ?

Comment: not more elegent way, but it will work even when the parameters will be nil and avoiding if else condition

Comment: I didn't know about optional parameters in routes. This looks like a good way to have nil parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No really great options here, but maybe one of these will help spark an idea:

---

```
args = { :action => "action1" }
args[:foo] = bar unless bar.blank?
redirect_to args
```

---

```
redirect_to { :action => "action1" }.tap do |args|
  args[:foo] = bar unless bar.blank?
end
```

---

```
redirect_to { :action => "action1" }.merge!(bar.blank? ? {} : { :foo => bar })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
redirect_to :action => "action1", bar.blank? ? {} : :foo => bar
```

Comment: If `bar` is blank, this will nest a weird hash element in the structure passed to `redirect_to`, something like `{:action=>"action1", {}=>"    "}` (where the value is the value of `bar` because of weird operator precedence).

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".