# Rails routing forcing param to be present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm fairly new to ruby api development and have created the below endpoint in my `routes.rb`

```
get "/users/active_users/:since"
```

However, when the param is not given, I want the param to default to a certain value. How do I enforce this? Also, I want to enforce that param be an integer and not alpha/alpha-numeric. Help is appreciated!

Comment: create a route with the optional parameter, check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39241338/5934752, and then check in controller if params present and if it is integer

Comment: That worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
get "/users/active_users/:since"
```

By making this routes its compulsory to give the `params[:since]` , other wise it will throw back a error `not routes matches`

So here by i would suggest you to make routes

```
get "/users/active_users"
```

Since it's `get` type request so its won't affect more, you can append `params[:since]` in query with routes like this:-

```
/users/active_users?since=1999
```

And at your controller you will get `params[:since] = 1999`

So far as i know it can't be enforce routes to accept only integer `params` but it can be handle at controller side

```
params[:since].is_a? Integer
=> true
```

Or

```
params[:since].to_i
```

Comment: Definitely helped, Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Could you accept/upvote answer if it helped you.?